# "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL..." with local files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I'm trying to access an iframe contents from the document it is contained in, but I'm getting the following error message:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   file:///home/user/work/project/foo.html from frame with URL
>   file:///home/user/work/project/index.html. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

when I run this code:

```
$('#iframe_id').contents();
```

As you can see, both files are stored locally in the same folder, so can't figure out why it is giving that error.

Comment: have you tried to use a local webserver (using `http` protocol rather than `file` protocol)?

Comment: Thank both of you, that did the trick. I'm using Aptana Studio 3, and running it as a javascript application worked

Comment: Changed my comment to an answer, didn't mean to comment in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome as security measures in place around local files. Meaning browsing local files isn't the same as browsing a web server. I would try hosting them somewhere or install a local web server. There is also some command line switches for chrome to disable the local files security but I have never had much luck with it.

Edit:

comand-line switch as mentioned by El Ronnoco is --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be a dirty workaround for this in your development version if you start chrome with the [command-line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 1):

Change your url to `http://www.your-domain.com/foo.html`.